# Calling the php function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, datepicker

Can anyone tell me what is the problem with the following code? I have chosen a date through JQuery Datepicker. It gets passed in the url onSubmit. I have to check if this date is equal to any of the dates from the database (for which I have used the mysql_fetch_array($getDates_query). Also, I have used localStorage to store the datepicker date. Can I pass this value into a php variable and then check it? If possible, how? Thanks.

Here is my code.
To select a date:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
   dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"   
});
$('form#dateform').submit(function(){   
var aselectedDate = $('#datepicker').val();

localStorage.setItem('adate', aselectedDate);
});
});
</script>
```

Connecting to the database:

```
mysql_select_db("trainingschedule",$con);
$sql="SELECT * FROM events_schedule";
$myData=mysql_query($sql,$con);
echo "<form id=\"dateform\" name=\"dateform\" action=\"#\" method=\"POST\ onSubmit=\"function1()\"><br><br>

<table>

<tr><td>
<b>Select a date &nbsp;&nbsp;<b></td><td><input id=\"datepicker\" name=\"date\" size=\"15\"/></td></tr>

</table>
<br>
<input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</form>";
```

The php function to check whether the selected date is matching any date from the date base is:

```
function function1()
{
$sql1="SELECT event_date from events_schedule";
$getDates_query= mysql_query($sql1,$con);

$adateStringValue = $_GET['dateform'];

while($fetchdates = mysql_fetch_array($getDates_query)) {
if ($fetchdates['event_date'] == $adateStringValue) {

$message = "You have selected this date";
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
}
else {
$message1 = "Selected this date";
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message1');</script>";
}

}
}
```

The problem here is that the function1() isn't getting called onSubmit. How can I rectify this problem?

Comment: The name of your date field appears to be 'date', not 'dateform' ?

Comment: A few words about indenting your code: Please remember to properly indent your code.

Comment: @Taplar Thank you! Corrected it! But it didn't solve the problem yet. The alert message isn't getting displayed.

Comment: @Blazemonger.. Thank you for your suggestion.. Will implement it. :)

Comment: @newbie Have you checked to see that your datepicker selection, and the dates in your database are the exact same format?

Comment: @wrxsti I was facing a problem with the format of both the dates. In the code I posted, the format of datepicker date is yyyy-mm-dd and the database date is in the string format( I couldn't get both the dates into the same format and hence I thought of storing the date values in db as a string and getting the datepicker date into a php variable and comparing both the dates.

Comment: Consider using http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php instead of fetch_assoc. It is much more efficient, and faster for the type of query you are doing. Then your conditional could simply be if(mysql_num_rows($getDates_query) > 0).

Comment: Also consider switching to mysqli. Its much safer, and is object oriented. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.overview.php

Comment: Is that the reason why the code didn't work? Using mysql_num_rows is definitely a better option though.

Comment: @newbie no that wasn't the cause of the issue, but I figured I would suggest it anyways.